# How to Make DatePicker Only Show Spinner Using Java

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to get a user to select a date by clicking on a button and having a datepicker dialog show up. However, no matter how I change the xml file, the spinner view won't show up, and I'm under the impression that the xml file isn't even being used.

```
public class Page extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private Calendar calendar;
private EditText date;
private DatePicker datePicker;
private int year, month, day;

static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_page);

    date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
    datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    showDate(year, month + 1, day);

    ... [other unrelated code]

    Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerItems, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    ... [other unrelated code]


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setDate(View view) {

    showDialog(1);
}

 @Override
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (id == 1) {
 return new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
 }
 return null;
 }

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

 showDate(arg1, arg2+1, arg3);
 }
 };

 private void showDate(int year, int month, int day) {
 date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("/")
 .append(month).append("/").append(year));
 }
```

When the button is clicked, the method setDate is called. I initialized a datepicker earlier in my Java code, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Here's the xml for my datepicker:

```
 <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Edit: Log after clicking ImageButton
09-03 10:31:15.719    1895-1910/com.home.Home W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 10:31:15.720    1895-1910/com.home.Home W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa54a3420, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Edit: XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.home.Home.Home">

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/selectDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/select_date"
    android:text="@string/select_date"
    android:onClick="setDate"/>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:hint="@string/date_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your code for your implementation of AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener (onItemSelected)?  Is this is where you bring up the date picker dialog?

Comment: I didn't use that to bring up the date picker dialog, it's actually for another spinner I have on the same page. Should I have something for the date picker there?

Answer (score 4):

```
datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
```

**Or use this in the XML**

Add this line to the code

```
android:calendarViewShown="false"
```

So it should look like this

```
 <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Comment: This has been deprecated since API 24 but I couldn't quite find what alternative they provided :/ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker#setCalendarViewShown(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice that you declared datepicker and you are using it as datePicker?, the program should not compile if you have that kind of errors. And as said Nate please upload the  spinner implementation of AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.

Comment: Fixed that, thanks. I actually have the AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener included for a different purpose, since I have a spinner on the page as well. I edited the code anyway, but it's not part of my DatePicker code.

Comment: @Kathy you are using a button for show up the dialog,right?

Comment: Yep! In my xml file, I set the onClick attribute for a button to "setDate" and I have a method called "setDate" in the code.

Comment: Oh, if it makes a difference, it's actually an ImageButton.

Comment: @Katty Could you upload the log after you click the ImageButton and you layout(The one that has the ImageButton), btw I executed your code and it worked with a layout that I made.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting the calendar display, but I have the spinner view randomly showing up before I click the button as well - I want the spinner view, not the calendar view, to show up when I click the button and to be invisible before then. Updating the code right now.